# $\text{SL}(3)$ is the graph of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that $\text{SL}(3)=\{A \in M_3(\mathbb R): \text{det}(A)=1\}$ is locally the graph of a $C^\infty$ function. I tried to apply the inverse, implicit, immersion and surjection theorems without success.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the notation of a Lie Group with a Lie Algebra. The Lie Group of matrices with determinant one is denoted $\mathrm{SL}(n)$. The associated Lie Algebra of traceless matrices is denoted $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$. We usually use capitals for the Lie Group and lower case for the Lie Algebra.

Comment: Try again with the implicit function theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SL(3)=\det^{-1}(\{1\})$.

The derivative $\det'_X$ of the determinant in a given point $X$ is given by the map

$$H \mapsto \det(X) \cdot \text{tr}(X^{-1}\cdot H).$$

It suffices to prove that this is a surjective linear map for every $X \in SL(3)$. Since it is a linear functional, it suffices to prove it is not the zero functional. But this is clear from taking $H=X$, from which we get that

$$\det_X'(X)= \det(X) \cdot \text{tr}(X^{-1}\cdot X)=3\det(X)=3. $$

The result now follows from the implicit function theorem.